# How do win streak bonuses work in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

I was watching [Hafu's](http://www.twitch.tv/itshafu) stream last night and she was coaching Trump on how to play a Miracle Rogue.

They went on a 5 game win streak from Rank 2 4 star to Rank 1 4 star and didn't get any bonus stars at all. I'm currently Rank 10 myself and still routinely get win streaks after 3 wins.

Do win streaks stop at a certain level? Are there different requirements at different ranks for win streaks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Do win streaks stop at a certain level?

Yes, you no longer get win streak bonuses at ranks 5 and higher.

> Are there different requirements at different ranks for win streaks?

No, it's always three wins at all ranks where win streaks exist.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Win streaks to stop at rank 5, but at lower ranks, two wins is enough for a streak.

Comment: I'm currently rank 20 and only get a streak at the third consecutive win. If it's only two for lower ranks, then "lower" refers to below 20.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need 3 wins for a streak even in the wooden ranks and I can't find anything on the internet saying otherwise (except for Matt's comment that is), so I assume Matt is simply mistaken.

Comment: Just to be sure, I just tested this on the Asia server. You definitely need 3 wins for a win streak even at the lowest rank.

Answer (score 4):

There are no bonus stars at rank 5 and above. Otherwise you could reach legendary rank with a win rate lower than 50%.

Comment: You can anyway, can't you? As long as your win rate is low enough when you reach rank 5.

Comment: @sepp2k I mean that from rank 5 on you have to win more than 50% of the games, or you'll never reach legendary.

Answer (score -1):

Moving from 21/2 to 20/1 as my 4th straight win, so at least after 4 wins a bonus (20/0 otherwise). I think we better keep it simple and think there is always a bonus after 3 wins, so the 3rd win gives one 2 stars, also at level 5 and above, that also makes it easier to move up as 50% win rate is enough.